# Python Inserting values into dictionary using a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, counting

I have a verses dictionary that contains these values:

```
{cluster1: 0, cluster2: 0, cluster3: 0}
```

i have a data file that has been read in and each line in the file has been represented as a string in a dictionary like this.

```
 [ "0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster3"," 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster2" ]
```

I want to be able to, for each line in the data file (represented as a string in a list), go through the dictionary and compare the Key values eg. cluster1 to see if it contains the substring "cluster1" 2 or 3. and then update the value in the dictionary accordingly. So the aim of the programme is to count the occurences of each cluster and have this represented as a dictionary with the clusternumber and the corresponding counts for each cluster.

I`m just not sure on the syntax to do this. here is my loop so far:

```
for verse in verses:
    for clusters[Key] in clusters:
        if clusters[Key] in verse:
            clusters.add(Key, +1) # tries to increment the value of 
                                  # the key if the key is in the string verse.
        else:
            print "not in"
```

Could someone give me some advice on where to go?

Thanks

Comment: How about reading the documentation about dictionaries? http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict and the data structures tutorial is also worth reading: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: The nested _for_ loops will become very slow if verses is long and there are many clusters.

Comment: Have we answered your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite close.  You need to look through keys of the dictionary:

```
for verse in verses:
  for k in cluster:
    if k in verse:
      clusters[k] += 1
    else: print "not in"
```

Comment: No, you dont need `.keys()`, just `for k in cluster`

Comment: this still doesnt seem to be working. It doesnt seem to be comparing the keys in the dictionary to the strings in verses and incrementing the key by 1. any ideas why?

Comment: is the line clusters[k] +=1 actually incrementing the value and not the key?

Comment: never mind, problem solved :) innacuracy in my data which caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use defaultdict and rsplit (split from right)

```
verses = [ "0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster3"," 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster2" ]

from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(int)

for verse in verses:
    key = verse.rsplit(',',1)[1]
    clusters[key] += 1

print clusters
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'cluster2': 1, 'cluster3': 1})
```

Comment: namedtuple in collections is very useful as well

Comment: @mike-pennington, it was nice to see it adopted into collections.  My favourite packages are _itertools_ and _collections_, I use them in every SO answer I can just to get them out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[ "0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster3"," 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,No,cluster2" ]
d={'cluster1': 0, 'cluster2': 0, 'cluster3': 0}
for line in l:
    tokens = line.split(',')
    d[tokens[-1]]+=1

print d
```

Returns

```
{'cluster2': 1, 'cluster3': 1, 'cluster1': 0}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote—I don't think yours is a bad answer—but I did edit out a bit of erroneous code.

Comment: that's OK Adam, I left it in so the OP would see that what he had posted caused an error. but it's a moot point now anyway :^)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. My apologies.